# What could prevent my forms app from running on a client?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have a windows forms app that runs fine on my development machine.  I published it and can successfully run the setup on the client. It installs the app in the program start menu as expected but when I click on it I get nothing. What possibilities could be occurring that causes this phenomenon? It runs a Crystal Report but since the form will not come up, I'm not even that far.

Comment: Have you checked the Event Viewer for error messages? (Typically crashes are recorded at Windows Logs -> Application.)

Comment: Thanks.  That does give me something to look at. 
 Exception Info: 
System.BadImageFormatException
   at CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils..cctor()

Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
   at CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils.get_CurrentControl()
   at CrystalDecisions.Shared.SharedUtils.GetEffectiveCulture()
   at CrystalDecisions.Shared.LocaleManager..ctor()
   at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer.InitReportViewer()
   at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer..ctor()
   at DSP_Report.DSPApp.InitializeComponent()

Comment: Thank you so much Joe Sewell.  That simple advise helped me to find I have to force rebuild in 64 bit.  That solved my problem.  This will be well remembered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Joe Sewell. His comment lead me to the solution which a referred to in my comment.